# Scala: recursive match case?

Tags: scala, class, recursion, match, case

I have a trait with two classes: C1 having a name (String) and children (List of String), and C2 having a text (String). Basically, I want to select all the C2 classes to get the text in their String. However, these C2 classes are children of C1 classes. For example, it goes like this : `C1("first", List(C1("firstchild", List(C2("text"))))`.

My idea was to do a recursive match case that stops when it finds a C2 class to give me the text inside it. If it finds a C1 class instead, it starts over with the children of this class (then if it finds a C2 class, it gives me the text, and if it finds a C1 class, if starts over with its children, etc.). But I'm stuck to do the recursive part. I mean, it appears that match cases are made to be a certain type only so I would have to make every case a Unit?

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

trait C {
  def getName: String
}

case class C1(private val name: String, children: List[C]) extends C {
  @tailrec
  private def rec(children: Seq[C]): String = {
    children match {
      case Nil => name
      case h :: t => h match {
        case c1: C1 => rec(c1.children)
        case c2: C2 => c2.getName
      }
    }
  }

  def getName: String = rec(children)
}

case class C2(private val name: String) extends C {
  def getName: String = name
}
```

Comment: Good answer, a couple of recommendations. **case classes** should be `final`. Do not use a `Seq`, especially if you are going to **pattern match** it and you know the input will be a **List**. The **trait** should be `sealed`. I would move the method to the **companion object** of `C`. And do not use `case c1: C1` but instead `case C1(_, children)`. Finally, I am not sure if the emtod should return the first `C2` but rather accumulate all the `C2` until the end of the recursion.